# I want to draw each mapped index of the array data[6] one at a time

Tags: p5.js

I have data mapped out and i want to separate the array: data[6] so that each index is mapped and drawn sequentially. for instance, draw index 0, the first circle, then have that disappear, and then draw index 1, etc.

I have tried to use a timer function but it still draws them all at once. I have tried putting the code in setup and in draw, but that has made no difference. I am relatively new to p5.js, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
var cities;

var lat = 0;

var lng = 0;

var clat = 0;
var clng = 0;

var zoom = 2;

function preload(){
cities = loadStrings('shootings.csv');

}

function setup() {
createCanvas(1980, 1020);
  translate(width/2, height/2);
  imageMode(CENTER);

}

function draw(){


var cx = mercX(clng);
    var cy = mercY(clat);

  for (var i = 0; i < cities.length; i++) {
        var data = cities[i].split(/,/);
        // console.log(data);
        var lat = data[4];
        var lng = data[5];
        var victims = data[6];

        victims = pow(10, victims);
        victims = sqrt(victims);

        var victimsmax = sqrt(pow(5, 5));

        var x = mercX(lng) - cx;
        var y = mercY(lat) - cy;
        var d = map(victims, 1, victimsmax, 0, 100);



        stroke(0, 0, 255);
        fill(0, 0, 255, 10);
        ellipse(x, y, d, d);


}



function mercX(lng) {
  //sets unit of measurement as radian, not degrees
  lng = radians(lng);
var a = (256 / PI) * pow(2, zoom);
  var b = lng + PI;
  return a * b;
}

function mercY(lat) {
   //sets unit of measurement as radian, not degrees
  lat = radians(lat);
var a = (256 / PI) * pow(2, zoom);
  var b = tan(PI/4 + lat/2);
  var c = PI - log(b);
  return a * c;
}


}
```

Answer (score 0):

The way I would go about it is to handle the data in the `preload()` function and then use `framerate()` to control the speed of the sketch. The `draw()` function is called 60 times per second and the ellipses are **all** being drawn each time; if you were to tell it to draw one at a time, a control variable would be needed.

Take a look at this sketch.

```js
let circles = [];

function preload(){
  // DATA HANDLING (Just some random circles)
  for(let i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    circles[i] = {
      radius:random(1, 20),
      x:random(0, 500),
      y:random(0, 200),
      color:[random(0, 255), random(0, 255), random(0, 255)]
    };
  }
}

function setup(){
  createCanvas(500, 200);
  frameRate(1);
}

// CONTROL VARIABLE
let currentlyDrawn = 0;

function draw(){
  if(currentlyDrawn < circles.length){
    // ERASE PREVIOULSY DRAWN CIRCLE
    clear();
    let c = circles[currentlyDrawn];
    fill(c.color);
    circle(c.x, c.y, c.radius);
    currentlyDrawn++;
  }else{
    noLoop();
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.7.3/p5.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you Julian. I will try this right away. I am a little unsure of how to get my data into the above example, but I am going to try.

Comment: Well, since you're using [loadStrings()](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/loadStrings) you could move all the data handling to `setup()` and declare the mercX and mercY functions ouside of `draw()` (Which should be done, regardless)